# Android JNI native function read file

Tags: android, file-io, java-native-interface

Hi I'm using Android JNI to integrate a cpp into my android program.

My cpp program reads in a model from several files. In cpp we just write

```
Model model("model/face2.tracker")
```

and the model utility reads the file according to the relative directory.

So where shall I put the file on my android system? And how to write the relative directory? I've totally no idea on this.

If I were to put it on the sd card, then I have to add a "accessExternalStorage" permission and just read it from java. However is it the same for native code?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

All java code is running on the vm, so no difference between JNI and java code.

Comment: Thx. However I'm still confused about the file system on Android system. Where shall I put these external files?

Answer (score 0):

Your app has it's own folder for such file which you can get by calling `context.getFilesDir()` in the Java part of your app. This will most likely but not guaranteed point to */data/data/com.example.hellojni/files/model/face2.tracker* .
You can also do this call within JNI which is significantly more complicated. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620770/nullpointerexception-when-calling-getfilesdir-in-a-jni-call)